# How do I stop CoffeCup HTML editor (Version 15 Build 769) from creating a new folder when I test a webpage from a server?

Tags: css, html5, webpage

OK. I know this question is really long but I wanted to be specific. Let me explain in more detail. I am using CoffeCup HTML editor software to edit a website. I have started a Website Project using the feature in CoffeCup (CC). I have also included a private FTP server as part of the project. I verified that CC is indeed connected to that server. I set the Website Project Path to my Desktop/Cyroot Stuff/CYROOT. Now when I use CC's Test Webpage feature to test an HTML page from my local source I get this address: file:///C:/Users/XXXXXXXX/Desktop/Cyroot%20Stuff/CYROOT/public/index.html but when I test a page using my server source, CC creates a folder called CYROOT inside the Website Project Path, so the address becomes this: file:///C:/Users/XXXXXXXX/Desktop/Cyroot%20Stuff/CYROOT/CYROOT/public/index.html

You can see how terrible this can be since ALL the other pages of the website are now rendered useless because the file path has changed!

How do I stop CC from creating a new folder and tell it to just use the Website Project Path when testing from the server? I cannot fathom an instance when working on a website why you would want to change your directory path!!! One possible solution is to just copy and paste my entire project into the newly created path but of course that means, going and changing all the links in the HTML code!

ANY help regarding how CoffeCup's server Website Project mechanics work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.